# Error message "unable to open web site" with VS 2008 on Vista

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, frontpage

I am trying to open a project in VS 2008 and my domain account it in the administrator group.  I get this message:

> "Unable to open the Web site
>   'http://locahost'.  To access Web
>   sites on thie local IIS Web server,
>   you must run Visual Studio under an
>   Administrator account in order to have
>   access to the IIS metabase. 
>   Alternatively, instll FrontPage Server
>   Extensions (FPSE) and then grant FPSE
>   access to users who will run Visual
>   Studio"

[image]

Any body know what I need to do to fix this problem. I have tried modifying the shortcut to run as administrator but shouldn't have to do that if I am an admin on my machine.

Comment: I tried right clicking on the shortcut and selected run as administrator and now I get a message that says: "Unable to open the Web site 'http://localhost'.  To access local IIS Web sites, you must install the folowwing IIS components:  In addition, you must run Visual Studio in the context of an administrator account."

There are not components listed in the error message.

Comment: I get this error too with VS11 on the Win8 beta. The error first shows when adding an existing ASP project to a solution when VS11 complains that the conversion failed and directs me to the conversion log. The conversion log shows no errors. Trying to open the project in VS11 throws the error above. [David Basarab](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2469/david-basarab)'s answer below fixed it for me - make sure VS11 is running with administrator privileges.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might not have IIS setup properly on the local machine, I would verify your IIS configuration before continuing.  You can always create a website or webapplication that runs through cassini instead and provide a folder path vs a IIS path.

P.S. Even if you are a machine administrator, with vista if the access restrictions are on you must still always specify that you wish to run the application under an administrator context.

Answer (score 1):

Right click over the shortcut, and in Properties in the Compatibility tab, select Run As Administrator.

Also confirm IIS is installed. It is not installed by default on Vista. You have to go and Add/Remove Windows Components.

See [here](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/how-to-install-iis-on-windows-vista/).

Comment: When I try to set the properties of the shortcut the "Run this program as an administrator" checkbox is grayed out.

Answer (score 1):

I uninstalled IIS and then reinstalled using only the bear minimums and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

What worked for me:
- Windows 7 IIS Manager 
- Delete other websites in the list under 'Sites'
- Right click the site
- Edit Bindings
- The 'host name' property was empty. Once I typed the name of the website there, I was able to load my site through Visual Studio 2008.

Answer (score 1):

Open Control Panel-> Programs and Features->Turn Windows features on or off. Under the list of features open Internet Information Services tree and then open Web Management Tools and then select IIS 6 Management Compatibility checkbox. Click OK button and install the selected feature of IIS.

[image]

link: http://geekswithblogs.net/technetbytes/archive/2011/10/11/147255.aspx